# SQL - 'char' auto_increment problems

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

I'm currently trying to use an SQL file to add a table to my database in phpMyAdmin and then populate it with data. I have successfully done this on many occasions but I have run into a serious issue which I can't find a solution too regardless of what I try. Previously I have used 'int' as my primary key type but I must now use 'char' as my primary key type. This is where the problem seems to have come from. I have looked online and tried several solutions all with different outcomes. All outcomes equal failure.

I have shown my original code below which failed and caused me too look for solutions online but too no avail.

```
--
-- Table structure for table `practice`
--

CREATE TABLE `practice` (
`practice_Id` char(2) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`Practice_Name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`Practice_Address` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`practice_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `practice`
--

INSERT INTO `practice` VALUES(P1, 'Practice Head Office', '27, The Hill, Glasgow');
INSERT INTO `practice` VALUES(P2, 'Practice Unit 1', 'Unit 1, Houston Estate, Glasgow');
```

When I try and import this file to my database I get the following response:

```
#1063 - Incorrect column specifier for column 'practice_Id'
```

Now I found a solution to that on this very site. Simply add unsigned to the auto_increment and it should work as auto_increment works with ints and floats. I added this to the file and then tried to import it once more. Again this failed giving me even more errors which are shown below:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'unsigned auto_increment,
`Practice_Name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`Practice_Add' at line 6
```

I tried unsigned alone leaving out auto_increment but I got the same results as above.

I really need help as this seems impossible to pass. There are no syntax errors so it makes no sense. Any questions just ask but I've put my attempts above and all solutions I've found. I have other sql files with this issue so really this is a massive hurdle for me and my last work.

Comment: You don't have to have char primary key. You can continue using regular, numeric auto incremented primary key and have another character column that you mark as `unique`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to pass. Autoincrement only works with *numeric* fields. Semantically it makes no sense to "increment" a character string. Yes, you could say

```
'x' + 1 = 'y'
```

for a single character, but how do you increment a character *string?* How would you evaluate

```
"Bob" + 3
```

for example?

Comment: I do see your point. What would I do to get past the issues I'm having? Do I just leave out unsigned auto_increment or is there something else I should do?

Comment: Why have you switched from `int` to `char`?

Comment: Because the id required isn't just a number now. It's now P1 and not 01 for example. I have removed the unsigned auto_increment from the file and the file was successfully imported into the database. Thanks. So simple yet so difficult :) At least I hope that was how it works.

Comment: If you absolutely must have autoincrement behaviour you might be able to do something with a stored procedure.

Comment: I had looked into that but with 6 different tables in my database being connected I concluded that, that was abit too complicated for me at this stage. But I thanks you for your help. Let's hope I don't run into additional problems with my other tables.

Comment: If you do, you know where to find us. ;)